# Issue after moving sharepoint database

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

We are using SharePoint Foundation 2010 on a Windows 2008 R2 Server.
There were issues with the growt of the database so we moved the database from a local SQL 2008 R2 SQL express server to a 2012 SQL standard server.
The site works fine and performs like hell
But in the event log gets flooded with 5586 and 6398 Errors

All errors seem to be related to the `SP Diagnostic Timer jobs`.
Now I Disabled a few but I was wondering what's the hurt in disabling all the timer jobs.

Even better idoes someone know a solution into why I get these errors.
Access rights should not be an issue , the users executing the jobs is sysadmin on the database server.

This is one of the errors we are getting

> De uitvoeringsmethode van taakdefinitie Microsoft.SharePoint.Diagnostics.SPChangedObjectsDiagnosticProvider (id f0b4ba30-ad58-42bf-b034-6f29c7d66535) heeft een uitzondering veroorzaakt. Hieronder vindt u meer informatie.
>
> Incorrect syntax near '99901'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Their are couple of issues with the database.

1. Becuase you moved it from SQL express to Sql 2012 then might be compatibily issue. [check this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/21/sql-server-fix-error-incorrect-syntax-near-you-may-need-to-set-the-compatibility-level-of-the-current-database-to-a-higher-value-to-enable-this-feature-see-help-for-the-stored-procedure-sp_db/)
2. May be try to Run the [Upgrade-SPContentDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607813(v=office.15).aspx), will fix all the compatibility issues.
3. May be Permission issue. [check this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2012/02/09/sharepoint-error-6398-you-do-not-have-permission-to-run-sp-trace-create.aspx), may be not relevant but gives very good idea.
4. [Clear the SharePoint Config Cache](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx).
5. Recycle the Timer Service.

Comment: Hi Wegas, thanks for this . I will check it out one by one and let you know

Comment: When I let sharepoint upgrade my databases it stopped at point 8 . Than I manually upgradeded my database as Waqas mentioned in point 2 . this went well with 3 of the 5 databases. But afterwards I could update the other databases with the sharepoint wizzard . Now all errors are gone !!! many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I need to ask this, the new database use the same account that the old database? If is not, did you change it in the timer service?
The error 5586 is triggered when the timer job can´t communicate with the database or the account doesn´t have the right permission.

Comment: Hi Marco, good point , the database runs under a local NT Service account . the timer service runs under an admin account.    Should I change the username under which the database runs into a network account ?

Comment: Hi @Boris, You can use whatever acount that you want, but check if the account have full access to the database (usually sysadmin)
Personally I create a special account for this and I give it full access to the database.
Check if the Timer has the same account (under Log On) tab

Good Luck